# warning when: "sudo apt upgrade"

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm trying to install ros2. So, I followed the steps for installation ,but when I type the command "sudo apt upgrade -y" I get this message:[image: see photo]

I don't want to upgrade to another version of ubuntu ,I want ubuntu 20.04.
I don't know if ros2 is compatible with ubuntu pro.
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: No where does it say it will install a new version of the OS.

Comment: I don't see any warning.

Comment: David you mean like 20.04.3 , 20.04.4 , 20.04.5 etc? And now it will be pro?

Comment: Please read my Q&A and read about Ubuntu Pro, to properly understand what it is.